# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java300 in java.library.path only while testing

Tags: java, opencv, testng

I am currently try to develop Java application which will use OpenCV library. I was trying to test my openCV configuration using testNg framework like this:

```
@Test
public void openCVTest(){
    System.out.println("OpenCV configuration simple test:");
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat m = Mat.eye(3,3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    System.out.println("OpenCV matrix = " + m.dump());
}
```

However that produced an error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java300 in java.library.path
```

I have found multiple answers(even on stackoverflow) and they all suggested bad configuration with some solutions which i tried. In the end I tried to run same code but this time in app like this:

```
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println("OpenCV configuration simple test:");
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat m = Mat.eye(3,3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println("OpenCV matrix = " + m.dump());
    }
}
```

And it is working like it suposed to. So my question is, why isn't this working with testing framework? Perhaps somehow i must also configure openCV library for tests?

Comment: It appears like your top test doesn't have its java.library.path configured correctly to find it's native lib, where it is configured in correctly in your second example.  Do a system.out() on the java.library.path property from your second example and see what the value is.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I am gonna try it when I return from the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I solved it using absolute path in my tests like this:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp(){
    System.loadLibrary("lib/x64/opencv_java300");
}

@Test
public void openCVTest(){
    System.out.println("OpenCV configuration simple test:");
    Mat m = Mat.eye(3,3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    System.out.println("OpenCV matrix = " + m.dump());
}
```

And in my application I am loading it normally:

```
 public class App {

    static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println("OpenCV configuration simple test:");
        Mat m = Mat.eye(3,3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println("OpenCV matrix = " + m.dump());
    }

 }
```